# symfony default locale language

Tags: symfony, translation, locale

i am trying for three hours change language at my website.

I am using version 2.1.7 and i found some articles  that from version 2.0 locale was accesible via session. But now is via request.

So i found at documentation this:

```
        $request=$this->getRequest();
        $locale=$request->getLocale();

        echo $locale;
```

Ok .. that works ... but i see 'en' which is default value in parameters.yml ... i have file messages.en.yml ... works ok.

But when i try: (where $localExtension ='fr' ... with existing messages.fr.yml file..)

```
     public function changeLanguageAction($localExtension) 
{
        $request=$this->getRequest();
        echo $localExtension;
        $request->setLocale($localExtension);

        return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
}
```

And after redirect i still see 'en' ... whats wrong? :/

Or how can i setLocale for everypage not only at one ...

Comment: $request->setLocale($newLocale) doesn't modify referer !

Comment: You redirect to referer that is unchanged by what you did before. Referer can't be modified by request object.

Comment: hm.. ok but what about this?             $url=$this->generateUrl("tb_welcome_page_homepage");
            return $this->redirect($url);

Comment: am i going to even good on it? I though there will be no problem to just change language in symfony hm...